# Wordpress CUstom Fields Default Fields in Admin View

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, custom-field-type

I have written a ton of custom fields to use with a template, but they are not showing up immediately in the admin view of the Page/Post and I have to manually type in all of the custom field names.

Is there a way to automatically make my fields show in the admin view, so I can immediately choose them from the dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way may be to do the following. Add this to your themes functions.php file [http://pastebin.com/NyqS2uPr](http://pastebin.com/NyqS2uPr.) - Code was rather long, sorry.

Once you add that, you'll see that under posts there is now a new "custom" menu. Entering items into this will allow you to add custom fields (determined by the code). This is a little cleaner than just having the dropdown as you can pre-determine what the custom field names will be.

Comment: wow, thanks. i assume if i need to put this code on a ton of different sites, i can put it inside a hook that can put this code into the functions.php file when the plugin is activated?

Comment: how would i call the variables/values in the template?

Comment: You would simply get the custom field as always. If you save a post with these parameters filled out and then scroll down, you'll see that custom fields have been filled out. Then, get the custom field: echo get_post_meta($post->ID, your_custom_field, true);

Answer (score 0):

While I'll usually add custom fields to the functions.php file, another option I've successfully used before is to add them using a free plugin.  The best custom fields plugin  I've found is called "More Fields".  The [More Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/) plugin is available on wordpress.org and its very easy to use (and doesn't require any actual coding).  There are a few more plugins you can also choose from if you like them better.

It's really your call on if you want to go the .htaccess route or the plugin route.  Both have their advantages, but I wanted to at least share the plugin I've had good luck with in the past.

Comment: the plugin is cool, but writing your own code beats using someone else's any day.